# getProductListJSON need more data

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

There is a part of the code that calls the getProductListJSON javascript function that looks like this

```
$.getJSON(storeRootUrl + "jsoncatalog/product/list/id/"+id, function(jsonObj) {
    renderProductList(jsonObj,sid);
});
```

It returns the image, product name, description and id.

I would like it to return a bit more, like the type of product, as in "simple, configurable, etc"

Based on the layout:

```
<jsoncatalog_product_list>
        <reference name="content">  
            <block type="paypal_catalog/json_product_list" output="toHtml" name="product_list"/>
        </reference>
    </jsoncatalog_product_list>
```

Looking at app\code\community\Paypal\Catalog\Block\Json\Product\List.php (hopefully I am looking in the right place), I can see the following code, wich I assume returns the data.

```
public function _toHtml()
    {
        try {
            $array = array();
            $category = Mage::registry('pp_current_category');
            if (!is_null($category)) {
                $array = Mage::helper('paypal_catalog')->getProducts($category->getId());
                $this->setCurrenCategoryKey($category->getId());
            } else {
                $array = array('category' => '', 'items' => array());
            }
            return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Where can I add the extra fields in that I need?

Am I on the right track, or even looking at the right template / php code that returns the data?

Please help me out here, I have not done Magento development for 2 years, so I have to re-learn allot of this stuff again....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following code, which is not the most efficient, but there are never more than 5 products in the list of this mobile app solution...

Added code to:

```
$array = Mage::helper('paypal_catalog')->getProducts($category->getId());
$this->setCurrenCategoryKey($category->getId());
```

And made it:

```
$array = Mage::helper('paypal_catalog')->getProducts($category->getId());
foreach ($array['items'] as &$productitem) {
    $productId = $productitem['id'];
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    if(!is_null($product)){
        $productitem['type'] = $product->getTypeId();
        //Get all options for product
        $options = array();                 
        $options = $product->getOptions();
        if (count($options) > 0){
            $productitem['hasoptions'] = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            $productitem['hasoptions'] = '0';
        }
        $addTocartUrl = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);
        $productitem['addTocartUrl'] = $addTocartUrl;
    }
    else{
        $productitem['type'] = 'simple';
        $productitem['hasoptions'] = '0';       
    }
}
$this->setCurrenCategoryKey($category->getId());
```

I was then able to change my footer.phtml with the following:

```
<!-- Product List Template -->
<div id="productListTemplate">
    <li onclick="checkQuickAdd(jQuery(this),'%url%');">
        <div class="product-image">%image%</div>
        <div class="product-content">
            <div class="product-title">%title%</div>
            <div class="product-description"><span class="counter" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:large;"></span> %description%</div>
            <div class="product-price">$%price%</div>
            <div class="quickadd"><a href="#" class="quickaddlink">+</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-id" style="display:none;">%id%</div>
        <div class="product-hasoptions" style="display:none">%hasoptions%</div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Which allowed to query the values later on in a js function:

```
function checkQuickAdd(listitem,url)
{
    var hasOptions = jQuery(listitem).find(".product-hasoptions").text();
    var productId = jQuery(listitem).find(".product-id").text();
    var productTitle = jQuery(listitem).find(".product-title").text();
    if (hasOptions == '0'){

            try {
                jQuery(".ui-loader").css("display","block");
                var cartUrl = "/index.php/test/jsoncheckout/cart/add/product/" + productId;
                var cartno = jQuery(jQuery('.ui-page-active .menu-bar-item.itemright>div')[0]).attr('id').replace("cartCount","");
                var cartCount = jQuery(jQuery('.ui-page-active .menu-bar-item.itemright>div')[0]).text();
                jQuery.ajax( {
                    url : cartUrl,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType : 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success : function(data) {
                        //alert("added");
                        var counter = 1;
                        var strCounter = jQuery(listitem).find(".counter").text();
                        if (strCounter != "") { counter = parseInt(strCounter) + 1; }
                        if (cartCount != "") { 
                            cartCount = parseInt(cartCount) + 1; 
                        }
                        else {
                            cartCount = 1;
                        }
                        jQuery(listitem).find(".counter").text(counter);

                        // update cart number
                        updateCartCount(cartCount, cartno);
                        jQuery(".ui-loader").css("display","none");        
                        alert("Added " + productTitle);
                    },
                    fail: function (msg) {
                        jQuery(listitem).find(".product-description").text(msg.d);
                        jQuery(".ui-loader").css("display","none");
                    }
                });
                jQuery(".ui-loader").css("display","none");
            } 
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
                jQuery(".ui-loader").css("display","none");
            }

    }
    else{
        forwardURL(url);
    }
}
```

This must be the most inefficient code that I have written in a long time, but the time frame was very small to complete this.

I would love to do this in a more efficient way.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: So basically, what my answer suggested?

Comment: I already did the Array post processing, but was looking for a more efficient example using app/code/community/Paypal/Catalog/Helper. Ran out of time for implementing a more efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed he place where output is made. However you need to dig deeper. Look at this line:

```
$array = Mage::helper('paypal_catalog')->getProducts($category->getId());
```

This fills the array where jsonEncode uses in the output routine. This is probably located somewhere in `app/code/community/Paypal/Catalog/Helper/`.

Alternatively, you can post-process that `$array` and add in your fields. However I strongly discourage that as you may have better luck (and performance) inside the helper method `getProducts` instead.

Good luck.